# Permissibility of the reed flute

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia

I've read that imam Rafi, a great shafi'i scholar allowed the reed flute whilst imam Nawawi disagreed with him. What evidence did imam Rafi'i use to justify his ruling?

Comment: The prominent shafi'i scholar which is known to have a lenient opinion regarding music was al-Ghazali. Ar-Rafi'i rather was a hardliner as far as I can tell. Actually an-Nawawi quoted him and commented his opinion.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I've heard the zahiri madhab also had a very lenient position regarding music as well, why was that?

Comment: @student they thought the hadiths prohibiting music were weak